# How do I concatenate a string and an enum in golang?

Tags: go, enums

I have the following structure.

```
package main

type MyEnum int

const (
    Foo MyEnum = iota
    Bar
)

func (me MyEnum) String() string {
    return [...]string{"Foo", "Bar"}[me]
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Field1 MyEnum
    field2 MyEnum
    Field3 string
}

func main() {
    info := &MyStruct{
        Field1: Foo,
        field2: Bar,
        Field3: "hello"
    }

    fmt.Printf(info.Field3 + info.Field1) //error here
}
```

The error is this :

```
invalid operation: info.Field3 + info.Field1 (mismatched types string and MyEnum)
```

So how do I concatenate a string and the string representation of an enum?

Comment: This is unrelated to enums but how the Go type system works.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
fmt.Printf(info.Field3 + info.Field1)
```

to

```
fmt.Printf("%v%v", info.Field3, info.Field1)
```